# how can I select one of multiple options with different probabilities?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a system where I can have multiple choices with multiple possible percentages/probabilities. Eg

```
A - 20%
B - 30%
C - 50%
```

I want to choose one of them based on the probability.  I can think of how to do it where I build ranges for each such as

```
A = 0-20
B = 20-50
C = 50-100
```

But it seems messy that I have to build a range for B based on the values that came before in generating the other parts of the range.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

*I'm programming this in PHP - extra points for code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571578/random-value-from-array-by-weight-in-php

Comment: thanks @JensW - the answer I wanted was http://stackoverflow.com/a/12571681/214545  The other answers are more memory/cpu intensive I think