# Generate a random number from a given set of numbers and chances

Tags: php, algorithm, random, probability

I have a list of numbers like

```
 $list = array(1,5,19,23,59,51,24)
```

in actual code this is generated from database, so this array will hold up to 500 numbers that are different from each other.

each of these numbers in the database has a probability of occurring recorded. So i have a data from previous executions to generate random numbers from 1 to 500 and recorded the probabilities of each number generated for like 1000 times.

Now having list of numbers and probabilities for each number i want to write a function that will generate a random number from these 500 numbers based on their probabilities.

For example:

```
    number 1 has a chance of: 0.00123 //0.123%
    number 6 has a chance of: 0.0421 //4.21%
    number 11 has a chance of: 0.0133 //1.33%
```

so variable $finallist will look something like this:

```
   $finallist[1] = 0.00123;
   $finallist[6] = 0.0421;
   $finallist[11] = 0.0133;
```

Now if i run my function and pass in $finallist as a parameter i want to retrieve a random number between 1 and 6 but number 6 will have higher possibility of coming out than 1 and 11 will have higher possibility to come out than 1.

I have some functions written that deal with returning the random number based on its chance but it only takes 1 value as a parameter.

```
private function randomWithProbability($chance, $num, $range = false)
{
    /* first generate a number 0 and 1 and see if that number is in the range of chance */
    $rand = $this->getRandomFloatValue(0, 1);

    if ($rand <= $chance) 
    {
        /* the number should be returned */
        return $num;
    }
    else 
    {
        /* otherwise return a random number */
        if ($range !== false)
        {
            /* make sure that this number is not same as the number for which we specified the chance */
            $rand = mt_rand(1, $range);
            while ($rand == $num)
            {
                $rand = mt_rand(1, $range);
            }

            return $rand;
        }
    }
}
```

if anyone knows a solution/algorithm to do this or if there is anything built in to PHP would be a big help. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'll let someone who speaks PHP write the answer (which can be you you), but here is the general idea. What you want to do is create an array containing the cumulative distribution, i.e. a running total of your probabilities. Then you choose the greatest index for which rand does not exceed the cumulative distribution.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and it doesnt at the same time. I dont get how choosing greatest index will give me random that has higher probability

Comment: "i want to retrieve a random number between 1 and 6 but ... 11 will have higher possibility to come out than 1" I think you have either unneeded information here, or you've got a mistake...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random results by weight in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445235/generating-random-results-by-weight-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic algorithm you're looking for:

- add all the probabilities together and determine the maximum
- pick a random number between 0 and 1 and multiply it by the max
- find the entry that corresponds with that value

Example code:

```
<?php

// create some weighted sample data (id => weight)
$samples = array(
  'a' => 0.001,
  'b' => 0.004,
  'c' => 0.006,
  'd' => 0.05,
  'e' => 0.01,
  'f' => 0.015,
  'g' => 0.1
);

class Accumulator {
   function __construct($samples) {
      // accumulate all samples into a cumulative amount (a running total)
      $this->acc = array();
      $this->ids = array();
      $this->max = 0;
      foreach($samples as $k=>$v) {
         $this->max += $v;
         array_push($this->acc, $this->max);
         array_push($this->ids, $k);
      }
   }

   function pick() {
      // selects a random number between 0 and 1, increasing the multiple here increases the granularity
      // and randomness; it should probably at least match the precision of the sample data (in this case 3 decimal digits)
      $random = mt_rand(0,1000)/1000 * $this->max;
      for($i=0; $i < count($this->acc); $i++) {
         // looks through the values until we find our random number, this is our seletion
         if( $this->acc[$i] >= $random ) {
            return $this->ids[$i];
         }
      }
      throw new Exception('this is mathematically impossible?');
   }

   private $max; // the highest accumulated number
   private $acc; // the accumulated totals for random selection
   private $ids; // a list of the associated ids
}

$acc = new Accumulator($samples);

// create a results object to test our random generator
$results = array_fill_keys(array_keys($samples), 0);

// now select some data and test the results
print "picking 10000 random numbers...\n";
for($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
   $results[ $acc->pick() ]++;
}

// now show what we found out
foreach($results as $k=>$v) {
   print "$k picked $v times\n";
}
```

The results:

```
> php.exe rand.php
picking 10000 random numbers...
a picked 52 times
b picked 198 times
c picked 378 times
d picked 2655 times
e picked 543 times
f picked 761 times
g picked 5413 times
```

Running the same code with this sample:

```
// samples with even weight
$samples = array(
   'a' => 0.1,
   'b' => 0.1,
   'c' => 0.1,
   'd' => 0.1
);
```

Produces these results:

```
> php.exe rand.php
picking 10000 random numbers...
a picked 2520 times
b picked 2585 times
c picked 2511 times
d picked 2384 times
```

Comment: Or, since you're going through the whole array anyway, you can just keep a single variable that keeps track of the accumulation as you go through the array.

Comment: thanks, this helped a loooot and it was way more than i was expecting. I appreciate your help, it worked and its perfect solution. Thanks alot

Comment: np; it was fun to flex my stagnant PHP skills :) @jswolf19 if you think it can be optimized, submit an answer; I'll mark it up!

Comment: I doubt it'd make a huge difference with 500 entries, but you could do a binary search since you know the cumulative amount is always increasing ^_~