# Generate random numbers with weighted probabilites

Tags: php, algorithm, random

I want to select a number randomly, but based on probability from a group of numbers; for example (2-6).

I'd like the following distribution:

- 6's probability should be 10%
- 5's probability should be 40%
- 4's probability should be 35%
- 3's probability should be 5%
- 2's probability should be 5%

Comment: then how it is random ??

Comment: why everyone gives -ve rating imidiatly when i ask question

Comment: it's random, just not a uniform distirbution

Comment: you have to be clear stating your question!

Comment: Because you don't show what you've tried, what your research is and you question isn't clear at all.

Comment: it can be random for example when we throw a dice maximum times it comes 6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11872928/650405

Comment: I took a look at your previous Questions. Some hints: try to write with proper spelling (install a spell checker in your browser), use the [WYSIWYG tools](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) when writing, indent your code properly, write descriptive titles, read the guide [ask]. If your Q starts badly it's because you're failing in some (or all) of the previous hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is generate a number between 0 and 100, and see in what range the number is:

```
$num = rand(0, 100);
if ($num < 10) {
    $result = 6;    
} elseif ($num < 50) { // 10 + 40
    $result = 5;
} elseif ($num < 85) { // 10 + 40 + 35
    $result = 4;
} elseif ($num < 90) { // 10 + 40 + 35 + 5
    $result = 3;
} else {
    $result = 2;
}
```

Be careful, if your total probability isn't **equal to 1**, then sometimes `$result` will be undefined.

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy to do. 
Watch for the comments in the code below.

```
$priorities = array(
    6=> 10,
    5=> 40,
    4=> 35,
    3=> 5,
    2=> 5
);

# you put each of the values N times, based on N being the probability
# each occurrence of the number in the array is a chance it will get picked up
# same is with lotteries
$numbers = array();
foreach($priorities as $k=>$v){
    for($i=0; $i<$v; $i++)  
        $numbers[] = $k;
}

# then you just pick a random value from the array
# the more occurrences, the more chances, and the occurrences are based on "priority"
$entry = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
echo "x: ".$entry;
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a number between 1 and 100.

```
If      it's <= 10       -> 6
Else if it's <= 10+40    -> 5
Else if it's <= 10+40+35 -> 4
```

And so on...

Note: your probabilities don't add up to 100%.