# Echoing random array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$input = array("Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1","Test2");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];
?>
```

Bascially I want to echo `Test1` and `Test2` randomly - BUT I want `Test1` to show up 4x more than `Test2` does.

I'm guessing that by adding it in 4 times more than Test2, it should show up 4 times more - is that code correct or should I be doing it a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we modify your code slightly to run in a loop:

```
$input = array("Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test2");
$results = array("Test1" => 0, "Test2" => 0);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input);
    $results[$input[$rand_keys]]++;
}

var_export($results);
```

I get results that look like this:

```
array (
  'Test1' => 807,
  'Test2' => 193,
)
```

That looks pretty close to four times as much to me!

Note that I have changed your `array_rand` call so it only receives one result at a time, because otherwise look at what happens:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2); // get two results 
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];         // echo the first one
```

The results appear in the order they are in in the original array. In this case, that means that `Test2`, when it appears, will always be last, so will never show up in your results.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing that by adding it in 4 times more than Test2, it should show up 4 times more

This approach looks correct. Let's test it:

```
$input = array("Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test2");

for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
    $rand_key = array_rand($input, 1);
    $result[] = $input[$rand_key];
}

$values = array_count_values($result);
print_r($values);
```

The output I got was:

```
Array
(
    [Test1] => 80123
    [Test2] => 19877
)
```

It's **4.03094028274** times!

Although, in your example, you always echo the first element in the `$input` array, so it's **not random** at all. You need to access the `$random_keys` index instead:

```
$rand_key = array_rand($input, 1);
echo $input[$rand_key];
```

Note that I've changed the `array_rand()` statement so it only receives one value at a time.

This can also be done using [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle):

```
$rand_key = shuffle($input);
echo $input[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by having "Test1" 4times and "Test2" 1time in the array chance of "Test1" being displayed is 4/5 and "Test2" is 1/5. Meaning if you run it for 100 times you will get 80 Test1 and 20 Test2.

Take a look at this question as well:

[Generating random results by weight in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445235/generating-random-results-by-weight-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the two values, you could do this much more efficiently by just randomly selecting amongst them using [php's `rand()`](http://php.net/rand) and weighting the results to correspond to your desired output.

You want `"Test1"` 4/5 of the time and `"Test2"` 1/5 of the time you could do this easily like this:

```
echo (rand() > (getrandmax() / 5)) ? "Test1" : "Test2";
```

You can verify this does the right thing with a loop, as many of the other answers have done.

```
for ($ii = 0; $ii < 10000; ++$ii)
  $r[(rand() > (getrandmax() / 5)) ? "Test1" : "Test2"]++; 
var_export($r);
```

outputs

```
array (
  'Test1' => 8027,
  'Test2' => 1973,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always pick in the ratio of 4:1. For 5 chances, you're guaranteed to get 4 of "1" and 1 of "2". Is that really what you want? That's not the same thing as a 4:1 ratio over many tries.

You could have an `array("Test1", "Test2")`. Pick an index between 0 and 4 inclusive (equal chance of any one of the five). If 0 to 3 (less than 4), pick `$input[0]`. Otherwise (4), pick `$input[1]`.