# Eloquent - biased random selection of a record

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a model `Quote`, which has two properties: *quote* and *probability*. I want to select a random quote, but **quotes with higher probability must be selected more often**. For example, if we have

```
$q1->probability == 0.15
```

and

```
$q2->probability == 0.75
```

the latter must be **5 times more likely** to be selected. The following command makes a random quote selection:

```
$quote = Quote::orderByRaw('RAND()')->first();
```

But I need the selection to be **biased**, as it was mentioned above. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to just do this with MySQL, but this question has been raised and addressed with PHP before: [Generating random results by weight in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445235/generating-random-results-by-weight-in-php)

Essentially, you want to pull Quote IDs and Weights (`[ id => 1, weight => 0.5]`) and the sum of all weights (`0.90` in your example). Then, in no particular order, loop through the array and subtract each weight.

So if I have a MySQL table with these values,

```
[
    [ 'id' => 1, weight => 1 ],
    [ 'id' => 2, weight => 2 ],
    [ 'id' => 3, weight => 4 ],
]
```

You would then generate a number between `0` and `7`, because that is the sum of all weights. At this point, you take each item and subtract it from the random number. An example would look like this.

```
$quoteWeights = Quote::select('id', 'weight')->get();
$weightSum    = $quoteWeights->sum('weight');
$weightRand   = mt_rand(0, $weightSum);

foreach ($quoteWeights as $quoteWeight)
{
    // Subtract our weight from the rand.
    $weightRand -= $quoteWeight->weight;

    // If it's bust, we want to return the winning model.
    if ($weightRand <= 0)
    {
        // Refresh the model so we get all attributes.
        return $quoteWeight->fresh();
    }
}
```

That's untested code, but I wager on it running correctly.

If you have a high-load server or a huge quotation database, you may want to invoke caching on th first part.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Nice technique