# PHP Lottery according to chance percentage

Tags: php

My question not duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445235/generating-random-results-by-weight-in-php) because I want to return the ad number by the change that returned.

I am working on advertisements script, every advertisement have a different change. I want to show in every refresh ad by change percent, so:

Ad number #1 - 100

Ad number #2 - 500

Ad number #3 - 20

So to calculate percent of change I do - `100+500+20=620`, and then divide each ad change with 620.

```
so Ad #1 have 100/620 * 100 = 16.12%
Ad #2 = 500/620 *100 = 80.64%
and Ad #3=20/620 * 100 = 3.22%
```

these percents its the ad chance to show. now I want to do a lottery with this information to show an ad.

**Of course the percents its from 100% in total sum of all ads**

**I think** I need to use `array_rand` or `get_randmax` but I dont know how to start.
thanks for helping.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+weighted+random+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @misorude you should flag one of the answers as a duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random results by weight in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445235/generating-random-results-by-weight-in-php)

Comment: @Jafarrezaei its not my question, I edit now

Answer (score 0):

Small idea, here is evaluated - https://3v4l.org/gpEHc

```
<?php

$ads = [
    ["name" => "Ad 1", "points" => 100],
    ["name" => "Ad 2", "points" => 200],
    ["name" => "Ad 3", "points" => 500],
    ["name" => "Ad 4", "points" => 50],
    ["name" => "Ad 5", "points" => 20]
    ];

function getRandom($ads) {
    $pointsSum = array_sum(array_column($ads, "points"));
    $rand = rand(0, $pointsSum);
    $start = 0;

    var_dump($rand);

    foreach ($ads as $ad) {
        if (($ad["points"] + $start) > $rand) {
            return $ad;
        } else {
            $start += $ad["points"];
        }
    }
}

var_dump(getRandom($ads));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply generate a number between 1 and 62. If the number is between 1 and 2, then ad #3, if it is between 3 and 52, ad #2 and between 53 and 62, ad #3.

I don't know if there are automated ways to do that, but is seems quite efficient and simple.

Comment: I think about it but the ads created dynamiclly, I mean the numbers I get in the top its examples, its can be more than 3 ads - like 5 and 6 different ads with different chances.

Comment: @Din obviously 1, 62, 2, 52 should be variables, not fixed numbers

Comment: Sorry but I cant understand, can you add an example please? (If you dont understand my - I mean that I cant know how much variables to do, because I add the ads dynamiclly)

Comment: @Din made it quick and dirty, but that's the idea. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d8d72200f3dd14eefa2a6ab57223e77ae46f19f